# Laravel Seeder - create 2 users with my own selected emails by seeder

Tags: laravel

here is what we have in user factory by default

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

i want to create 2 users with lets say these email addresses in a seeder.

```
user1's email = abc@abc.com
user2's email = xyz@xyz.com
```

where i need to put my code. in seeder or in factory and how?

Comment: are you going to seed only these email or you are going to seed multiple and you want these two ids as a part of that data

Comment: only 2 sir. actually these 2 emails will be added as super admins. 2 users with different emails and only 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just create 2 emails, you can just put it in the seeder, you wouldn't need a factory there, and you can write it this way:-

First create the seeder:-

```
php artisan make:seeder UserTableSeeder
```

which will create you the following code, then you can add your data there:-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    App\User::create([
    'name' => 'name',
    'email' => 'abc@abc.com',
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ]);

         App\User::create([
    'name' => 'another name',
    'email' => 'xyz@xyz.com',
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ]);
    }
}
```

then you can run your seeder using this command:-

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder
```

but if you wanna create more than one user, then you can use [model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding#using-model-factories).

Comment: thanks. i will use $user = new User(); and $user->save(); because i need to call few methods on $user object to give it some permissions as well.

Comment: yvw,  creating a seeder for each model is better and you can adjust it, the way you like :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `DatabaseSeeder.php`, add the following code to the `run()` function:

```
    DB::table('users')->insert([

        ['id'=>'1', 'user'=>'User1', 'email'=>'abc@abc.com', 'email_verified_at' =>now(),
         'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', 'created_at' => now(), 'updated_at' => now()],

        ['id'=>'2', 'user'=>'User2', 'email'=>'xyz@xyz.com', 'email_verified_at' =>now(),
         'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', 'created_at' => now(), 'updated_at' => now() ],

    ]);
```

Comment: can i add by make objects like this? because i need to run methods on objects. 

$user = new User(); 

and at the end 

$user->save();

Comment: What he will do if he needs seeding in another model? that will show duplicate records, if he will use DatabaseSeeder.